# setImageDrawable did not set image on API23

Tags: android, android-gallery

I'm trying to set an image to my CircleImageView on Android API 23. I get the image path from the device's memory and store this string path to database:

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
  android:id="@+id/fragment_edit_picture"
  android:layout_width="150dp"
  android:layout_height="150dp"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:layout_margin="5dp"
  android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:onClick="selectFromGallery"
  app:civ_border_width="2dp"
/>
```

It is working on API 19 and before, but it's not working on a virtual device in Genymotion with Android version API 23. The selected image is not showing in the ImageView. I'm setting the image to the ImageView this way:

```
mCurrentImagePath = FileUtils.getPath(getActivity(), selectedImageUri);
Log.d(TAG, "mCurrentImagePath: " + mCurrentImagePath);

// Update client's picture
if (mCurrentImagePath != null && !mCurrentImagePath.isEmpty()) {
    fragmentEditPicture.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),
            FileUtils.getResizedBitmap(mCurrentImagePath, 512, 512)));
}
```

The image path is `mCurrentImagePath: /storage/emulated/0/Download/56836_(5-27-2006 2-28-40)(1920x1200).JPG`.

Do you know why this isn't working?

Comment: Have you requested the needed permissions at runtime ?

Comment: @OgnianGloushkov No.It doesn't get any Error or exception. It just doesn't set an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with the method you are using **FileUtils.getResizedBitmap()**. I created a sample project to reproduce your issue. It's working fine in that sample project. When using the code snippet below, you shouldn't have a problem loading images from the device's memory.

```
public static Bitmap getResizedBitmap(String imagePath, int width, int height) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, false);
    // Recycling the bitmap, because it's already used and not needed anymore
    bitmap.recycle();
    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

Comment: Recycle original `bitmap` after using it. Use `BitmapFactory.Options.inJustDecodeBounds` first.

Comment: @EugenPechanec buddy ,sorry I didn't get what you said exactly !! I am new in android.this is [FileUtils.getResizedBitmap()] (http://codepad.org/c33ilHxK)   .  and in method uses options.inJustDecodeBounds = false; what do i exactly ?according that I understand of your suggestion i have used this way [link](http://codepad.org/oiskWKwf).but i got error [link](http://codepad.org/wqGYmUHx).sorry and thank you so much

Comment: `mCurrentImagePath` is my path of image's selected not uri.

Comment: @sayreskabir Sorry about that. It probably confused you. Some of the bitmap methods require URI, but **BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath)** requires only String, which in the current situation is **mCurrentImagePath**. I edited my answer to not be confusing.

You can read more about URI in Android here: [Uri | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html)

Comment: @SlaviPetrov . Thanks . I am using in this way [link](http://codepad.org/usLfVebU). is it correct? But i got Error :[error] (http://codepad.org/paxS3SeQ). where is my problem?

Comment: @sayreskabir The problem is that you don't have permissions for reading from the device's memory. This row is telling you that permissions are the problem: `...E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/54924_(2560x1600).JPG: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)` and specifically **(Permission denied)**. You need to add this row `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` to the file **AndroidManifest.xml** between the tag '<manifest... >' and `<application...`.

Comment: @sayreskabir This way you will get permissions to read from the memory. Example here: [AndroidManifest.xml](http://codepad.org/B9W0DYFx)

Comment: @SlaviPetrov I add  permissions [Manifest] (http://codepad.org/wKRql6OD) but I got this error [error] (http://codepad.org/DlLAzO68).

Comment: @sayreskabir If you are trying this on API 23 device, you should request permissions at run time. You can read more about it here [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). If you just want to test that your code is working as expected go to device's **Settings**, find the application and give it permissions to read.

Comment: @SlaviPetrov I run this code on Api 19 but i got this error:[error](http://codepad.org/9Dv4Qo79).I am really sorry.

Comment: @sayreskabir Can you provide a code snippet where you get the `mCurrentImagePath`?

Comment: @SlaviPetrov. this is where I get Image from camera or gallery [link](http://codepad.org/EIXnTJes).

Comment: @sayreskabir I edited my answer and added recycle() method. Try this way, without using **BitmapFactory.Options.inJustDecodeBounds**.

Comment: @SlaviPetrov I have not real phone for trying my app on API 23 but in Api 19 it work. thanks buddy.